Rig Fur Tufts to a Body
I have these tufts of fur that are on arbitrary points on the body of my character. There isn't an easy single bone I can just attach it to.
I know about parenting to Tries, but that's not quite perfect. This mesh is being exported to Unreal. I'd prefer to have the fur tufts joined to the base mesh of the character ideally.
Any ideas?


